# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in for zend

Tags: zend-framework, htmlspecialchars

I have an error in file : Abstract.php

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,array given in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php on line 905
```

I have this on line 905 :

```
 public function escape($var)
{
    if (in_array($this->_escape, array('htmlspecialchars', 'htmlentities'))) {
        return call_user_func($this->_escape, $var, ENT_COMPAT, $this->_encoding);
    }

    if (1 == func_num_args()) {
        return call_user_func($this->_escape, $var);
    }
    $args = func_get_args();
    return call_user_func_array($this->_escape, $args);
}
```

i don't understand this...

Comment: maybe you give some more details so it is easier for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you added array to `$this->escape()` function.

If you don''t know where then add to file `Abstract.php` something like this:

```
if(is_array($var)){
  Zend_Debug::dump($var);//this will print variable causing problem
  //OR
  throw new Exception(' ');//this will print debug backtrace showing which line caused problem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue on  lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php
I did update below

```
protected function _escape($string)
    {

         return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT);     


    }
```

with

```
protected function _escape($string)
    {
      if(is_string($string)) {
         return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT);     
       }
      else
       {
              return $string;

        }   

    }
```

Thing started to work.